# Submit button unable to process javascript for verification

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, division

Would anyone know why my submit button wouldn't call javascript to verify if certain fields are populated in the form?

To have better idea I have provided a link to the website: http://www.flyingcowproduction.com/pls and click on the button "reservation" from the top menu.

Form:

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
                <div class="grid_6">
                    <div class="element">
                        <label>Name*</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="text" style="width:427px;" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="grid_3">
                    <div class="element">
                        <label>Email*</label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" class="text" style="width:200px;" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="grid_3">
                    <div class="element">
                        <label>Phone</label>
                        <input type="text" name="phone" class="text" style="width:200px;" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="grid_3">
                    <div class="element">
                        <label>Address*</label>
                        <input type="text" name="address" class="text" style="width:200px;" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="grid_2">
                    <div class="element">
                        <label>City*</label>
                        <input type="text" name="city" class="text" style="width:119px;" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="grid_1">
                    <div class="element">
                        <label>Zip*</label>
                        <input type="text" name="zipcode" class="text" style="width:55px;" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="grid_6">
                    <div class="element">
                        <label>Where do you want to go?*</label>
                        <input type="text" name="service" class="text" style="width:427px;" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="grid_3">
                    <div class="element">
                        <label>Date and time of service*</label>
                        <input type="text" name="datetime" class="text" style="width:200px;" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="grid_2">
                    <div class="element">
                        <label>Passengers (max)</label>
                        <input type="text" name="passingers" class="text" style="width:75px;" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="grid_1">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="grid_6">
                    <div class="element">
                        <label>Comment</label>
                        <textarea name="comment" class="text textarea" style="width:427px;" rows="4"  /></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="grid_6">
                    <div class="element">
                        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="MAKE RESERVATION" />
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>


<script type="text/javascript">
```

$(document).ready(function() {

```
//if submit button is clicked
$('#submit').click(function () {        

    //Get the data from all the fields
    var name = $('input[name=name]');
    var email = $('input[name=email]');
    var phone = $('input[name=phone]');
    var address = $('input[name=address]');
    var city = $('input[name=city]');
    var zipcode = $('input[name=zipcode]');
    var service = $('input[name=service]');
    var datetime = $('input[name=datetime]');
    var passingers = $('input[name=passingers]');
    var comment = $('textarea[name=comment]');

    //Simple validation to make sure user entered something
    //If error found, add hightlight class to the text field
    if (name.val()=='') {
        name.addClass('hightlight');
        return false;
    } else name.removeClass('hightlight');

    if (email.val()=='') {
        email.addClass('hightlight');
        return false;
    } else email.removeClass('hightlight');

    if (address.val()=='') {
        address.addClass('hightlight');
        return false;
    } else address.removeClass('hightlight');

    if (city.val()=='') {
        city.addClass('hightlight');
        return false;
    } else city.removeClass('hightlight');

    if (zipcode.val()=='') {
        zipcode.addClass('hightlight');
        return false;
    } else zipcode.removeClass('hightlight');

    if (service.val()=='') {
        service.addClass('hightlight');
        return false;
    } else service.removeClass('hightlight');

    if (datetime.val()=='') {
        datetime.addClass('hightlight');
        return false;
    } else datetime.removeClass('hightlight');

    //organize the data properly
    var data = 'name=' + name.val() + '&email=' + email.val() + '&phone=' + phone.val() + '&address=' + address.val() + '&city=' + city.val() + '&zipcode=' + zipcode.val() + '&service=' + service.val() + '&datetime=' + datetime.val() + '&passingers=' + passingers.val() + '&comment='  + encodeURIComponent(comment.val());

    //disabled all the text fields
    $('.text').attr('disabled','true');

    //show the loading sign
    $('.loading').show();

    //start the ajax
    $.ajax({
        //this is the php file that processes the data and send mail
        url: "process.php", 

        //GET method is used
        type: "GET",

        //pass the data         
        data: data,     

        //Do not cache the page
        cache: false,

        //success
        success: function (html) {              
            //if process.php returned 1/true (send mail success)
            if (html==1) {                  
                //hide the form
                $('.form').fadeOut('slow');                 

                //show the success message
                $('.done').fadeIn('slow');

            //if process.php returned 0/false (send mail failed)
            } else alert('Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later.');               
        }       
    });

    //cancel the submit button default behaviours
    return false;
});
```

});

many many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is fine and is getting called if one uses your provided html above. But the site you gave link of shows this

```
<input type="submit" value="MAKE RESERVATION" id="FormId">
```

see that id="FormId"  it should be "submit"

Ok now please try this

1) Make sure you backup things
2) Remove the validation function that we just added to index.html
3) Replace the last script block (which starts from line 358) on index.html with the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {     
    // Added by Prayas  (Start)
    function menuItemClick(section) {
        content1 = "loader.html " + section;
        toTheSky();
        $("#singleContentContainer").delay(400).fadeIn();
        $('#singleContentInside').load(content1);


          if(section=="#reservations")
            {
                    $('#submit').click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();    

                    //Get the data from all the fields
                    var name = $('input[name=name]');
                    var email = $('input[name=email]');
                    var phone = $('input[name=phone]');
                    var address = $('input[name=address]');
                    var city = $('input[name=city]');
                    var zipcode = $('input[name=zipcode]');
                    var service = $('input[name=service]');
                    var datetime = $('input[name=datetime]');
                    var passingers = $('input[name=passingers]');
                    var comment = $('textarea[name=comment]');

                    //Simple validation to make sure user entered something
                    //If error found, add hightlight class to the text field
                    if (name.val()=='') {
                        name.addClass('hightlight');
                        return false;
                    } else name.removeClass('hightlight');

                    if (email.val()=='') {
                        email.addClass('hightlight');
                        return false;
                    } else email.removeClass('hightlight');

                    if (address.val()=='') {
                        address.addClass('hightlight');
                        return false;
                    } else address.removeClass('hightlight');

                    if (city.val()=='') {
                        city.addClass('hightlight');
                        return false;
                    } else city.removeClass('hightlight');

                    if (zipcode.val()=='') {
                        zipcode.addClass('hightlight');
                        return false;
                    } else zipcode.removeClass('hightlight');

                    if (service.val()=='') {
                        service.addClass('hightlight');
                        return false;
                    } else service.removeClass('hightlight');

                    if (datetime.val()=='') {
                        datetime.addClass('hightlight');
                        return false;
                    } else datetime.removeClass('hightlight');

                    //organize the data properly
                    var data = 'name=' + name.val() + '&email=' + email.val() + '&phone=' + phone.val() + '&address=' + address.val() + '&city=' + city.val() + '&zipcode=' + zipcode.val() + '&service=' + service.val() + '&datetime=' + datetime.val() + '&passingers=' + passingers.val() + '&comment='  + encodeURIComponent(comment.val());

                    //disabled all the text fields
                    $('.text').attr('disabled','true');

                    //show the loading sign
                    $('.loading').show();

                    //start the ajax
                    $.ajax({
                        //this is the php file that processes the data and send mail
                        url: "process.php", 

                        //GET method is used
                        type: "GET",

                        //pass the data         
                        data: data,     

                        //Do not cache the page
                        cache: false,

                        //success
                        success: function (html) {              
                            //if process.php returned 1/true (send mail success)
                            if (html==1) {                  
                                //hide the form
                                $('.form').fadeOut('slow');                 

                                //show the success message
                                $('.done').fadeIn('slow');

                            //if process.php returned 0/false (send mail failed)
                            } else alert('Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later.');               
                        }       
                    });

                    //cancel the submit button default behaviours
                    return false;
                });
    }


    }

    $("#services1").click(function() {
        menuItemClick("#services")
    });
    $("#services2").click(function() {
        menuItemClick("#services")
    });
    $("#rates1").click(function() {
        menuItemClick("#rates")
    });
    $("#rates2").click(function() {
        menuItemClick("#rates")
    });
    $("#reservations1").click(function() {
        menuItemClick("#reservations")
    });
    $("#reservations2").click(function() {
        menuItemClick("#reservations")
    });
    $("#fleet1").click(function() {
        menuItemClick("#fleets")        
    });
    $("#fleet2").click(function() {
        menuItemClick("#fleets")        
    });

    $("#closeContainer").click(function() {
        downToEarth();
        $("#singleContentContainer").fadeOut();
    });     
    // Added by Prayas  (End)
});

</script>
```

EDIT 2

1) Remove the Script block at the bottom that we just added.
2) Copy the whole reservations div from loader.html into a new file named reservations.html.
3) Place the original validation function in this div back on its position in "reservations.html".
4) Place this script block at the end of your index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {     
    // Added by Prayas  (Start)
    function menuItemClick(section) {

    if(section=="#reservations")
    {
            content1 = "reservations.html;
    }
    else
    {
            content1 = "loader.html " + section;
        toTheSky();
        $("#singleContentContainer").delay(400).fadeIn();
        $('#singleContentInside').load(content1);
    }

    $("#services1").click(function() {
        menuItemClick("#services")
    });
    $("#services2").click(function() {
        menuItemClick("#services")
    });
    $("#rates1").click(function() {
        menuItemClick("#rates")
    });
    $("#rates2").click(function() {
        menuItemClick("#rates")
    });
    $("#reservations1").click(function() {
        menuItemClick("#reservations")
    });
    $("#reservations2").click(function() {
        menuItemClick("#reservations")
    });
    $("#fleet1").click(function() {
        menuItemClick("#fleets")        
    });
    $("#fleet2").click(function() {
        menuItemClick("#fleets")        
    });

    $("#closeContainer").click(function() {
        downToEarth();
        $("#singleContentContainer").fadeOut();
    });     
    // Added by Prayas  (End)
});

</script>
```

Comment: Im actually making changes as people are instructing me on how :) I switched back to submit. Sorry my bad

Comment: I see, somehow i cant seem to find your javascript code on that url? i viewed source and cant find your function anywhere

Comment: both, form and javascript are located inside loader.html file.

Comment: Sorry but i still cant find your javascript validation code there, i believe that is the only issue. Can you please double check. I viewed source of the page which contains your form and can't still find that jquery code

Comment: The javascript is located right above the form in loader.html file

Comment: Sorry, you might be disliking me by now but really your javascript is not going out on that page. Or maybe im too tired! there are other javascript codes there but not this validation function code. can you send link of loader.html ?

Comment: I am so thankful you are still patient with me on this :) I am frustrated with this problem and your help is greatly welcome. The link to the file is: http://flyingcowproduction.com/pls/loader.html. Basically index.html page via jquery is calling loader.html with all the content that goes inside hidden div. Best regards

Comment: Cool i think we are almost there. Your Jquery call for loader.html is stripping out your script code which contains your validation function. So you see your function in source code of loader.html but when it goes to your main page it goes without that javascript. that is the reason it isnt working

Comment: so, how do I make it work than? :D I am not sure why is not reading it

Comment: Try this, remove your validation function from loader.html and move it to index.html and leave all else same

Comment: I've tried, still the same :( I never though this problem would give me such a headache!

Comment: Don't worry we will get this sorted. You placed it before calling your jquery file. So please place it below the call for "default.js", not above it

Comment: Same thing :( this problem makes me want to laugh and cry at the same time LOL. It is bizarre! So you think everything is okay with the form itself?

Comment: Don't worry, relax its just a small issue of script not being executed in a load call. let me prepare another solution and lets try that

Comment: Im gona take your page and try it locally to see if it works. The only issue is that when you load html using jquery .load() function with a selector then it strips out your javascript and that is not executed. All other suggestions although might be correct but those are not the reasons why your validation is not working. The only reason is that your javascript is not getting loaded when you .load() reservations div.

Answer (score 3):

You should write:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    //Get the data from all the fields
    var name = $('input[name=name]');
    ...
```

Comment: thanks for such a fast reply. I tried your suggestion but still same problem persists. There is an id="submit" that should call the script but for some odd reason it never calls it and the script is located in my index.html file and the form is inside my loader.html file. I think there is some issue with jquery but I can't figure it out where :(

Comment: @devnate is correct, the form is submitted by the browser before the validation code has a change to run. I'll update my answer. EDIT: silly mistake, it's $('form') rather than $(form).

Comment: I've tried that too and I am prompted with the same error that is going to the process.php page before calling the javascript for verification :/

Comment: I've checked on your live website, but I can't see where is the verification code. Can you help ?

Comment: Hi Laurent, it is located at the very top of index.html page

Comment: OK, the problem is way more simple. You forgot to include jQuery in the page :). I have: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

Comment: You are using `$`, which is exported by jQuery. Yet it's not loaded anywhere in the page. You must add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` before your validation script.

Comment: It is incorporated inside my <script type="text/javascript" src="default.js"></script> file

Answer (score 1):

In your click event handler you'll probably want to prevent the default action of the click which is submitting the form before your code runs.

```
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

However, I'd do what Laurent said and bind on the form submit instead.

Comment: Still the same, nothing changed :/ This is so frustrating

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it on the Form's submit event.

First give your form an id, say "FormId"

```
$("#FormId").submit(function () {        

        //Get the data from all the fields
        var name = $('input[name=name]');
        var email = $('input[name=email]');
        var phone = $('input[name=phone]');
        var address = $('input[name=address]');
        var city = $('input[name=city]');
        var zipcode = $('input[name=zipcode]');
        var service = $('input[name=service]');
        var datetime = $('input[name=datetime]');
        var passingers = $('input[name=passingers]');
        var comment = $('textarea[name=comment]');

        //Simple validation to make sure user entered something
        //If error found, add hightlight class to the text field
        if (name.val()=='') {
            name.addClass('hightlight');
            return false;
        } else name.removeClass('hightlight');

        if (email.val()=='') {
            email.addClass('hightlight');
            return false;
        } else email.removeClass('hightlight');

        if (address.val()=='') {
            address.addClass('hightlight');
            return false;
        } else address.removeClass('hightlight');

        if (city.val()=='') {
            city.addClass('hightlight');
            return false;
        } else city.removeClass('hightlight');

        if (zipcode.val()=='') {
            zipcode.addClass('hightlight');
            return false;
        } else zipcode.removeClass('hightlight');

        if (service.val()=='') {
            service.addClass('hightlight');
            return false;
        } else service.removeClass('hightlight');

        if (datetime.val()=='') {
            datetime.addClass('hightlight');
            return false;
        } else datetime.removeClass('hightlight');

        //organize the data properly
        var data = 'name=' + name.val() + '&email=' + email.val() + '&phone=' + phone.val() + '&address=' + address.val() + '&city=' + city.val() + '&zipcode=' + zipcode.val() + '&service=' + service.val() + '&datetime=' + datetime.val() + '&passingers=' + passingers.val() + '&comment='  + encodeURIComponent(comment.val());

        //disabled all the text fields
        $('.text').attr('disabled','true');

        //show the loading sign
        $('.loading').show();

        //start the ajax
        $.ajax({
            //this is the php file that processes the data and send mail
            url: "process.php", 

            //GET method is used
            type: "GET",

            //pass the data         
            data: data,     

            //Do not cache the page
            cache: false,

            //success
            success: function (html) {              
                //if process.php returned 1/true (send mail success)
                if (html==1) {                  
                    //hide the form
                    $('.form').fadeOut('slow');                 

                    //show the success message
                    $('.done').fadeIn('slow');

                //if process.php returned 0/false (send mail failed)
                } else alert('Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later.');               
            }       
        });

        //cancel the submit button default behaviours
        return false;
    });
```